# Как в WPF изменить свойство элемента из кода?

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Есть UserControl.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Ellipse Width="40" Height="40">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="" />
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
        <TextBlock Text="" TextAlignment="Center" Name="userName" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Как изменить свойство ImageSource у элемента ImageBrush из кода.
Мне нужно привязать его к свойству UserPhoto внутри контрола.

```
    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return userName.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            userName.Text = value;
        }
    }

    public string UserPhoto
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }
```

Но у элемента ImageBrush нет свойства Name по которому его можно найти.

Comment: ну вы `Ellipse` найти можете? И его свойство `Fill`?

Comment: Никак, потому что ImageBrush — Freezable, вы можете только пересоздать целиком экземпляр `ImageBrush`. Итого, ваше решение — сделать конвертер, который будет создавать из строки новый экземпляр ImageBrush. И привязаться к свойству Fill через этот конвертер.